# Updating the Height of a Self-Sizing Table View Cell with a Text View

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I have a table view similar to the Compose screen in Mail, where one of the cells is used for text input. I'd like the cell to resize automatically by constraining the `contentView` of the cell to its `UITextView` subview using Auto Layout. The table view's `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` are set to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Additionally, the text view's `scrollEnabled` property is set to `false` so that it reports its `intrinsicContentSize`.

However, the cell does not update its height as lines of text are entered by the user, even though the text view itself *does* update its intrinsic content size. As far as I know, the only way to request this manually is for the table view to call `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`. The height of the cell is then correctly updated, but this also causes re-layout of the entire table view. Here's (someone else's) [sample code demonstrating the problem](https://github.com/jurezove/self-sizing-uitextview-in-a-table).

How can I reflect changes in the cell's text view without laying out the entire table view?

Comment: How have you solved this? Do you have a solution that does not jitter?

Comment: So far I've only found partial solutions. The first approach I tried, just calling `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` in `textViewDidChange`, is close to what I want. But then you have to deal with the whole table view layout becoming invalidated, and subsequent scrolling. Alternatively, reloading the row could work _if_ it could be done with no visible interruption, but that starts to lead into hacky KVO stuff with Core Animation that I'd rather avoid.

Comment: Trouble with `beginUpdates`+`endUpdates`: starts jittering when top of cell is out of sight. Trouble with `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`: cancels editing so keyboard goes away. I have had reasonable success with a **throttled** solution.

Answer (score 3):

## Throttled Solution

The trouble with `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is that the `UITextField` will `resignFirstResponder` since the cell, in essence, is reloaded: *i.e. destroyed*.

Conversely, `beginUpdates()` & `endUpdates()` do maintain the existing cells, yet jitters when invoked on a cell containing a `scrollEnabled` `UITextView` if triggered with every single `textViewDidChange`.

**Limit the updates frequency**

This solution is based on the popular `textViewDidChange` approach, only reduces or stops flickering entirely by postponing the update.

**Subclass `UITableViewCell`:**

```swift
class TableViewTextViewCell : UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    var refreshCell:(() -> Void)? = nil
    var textViewDirtyCount = 0

    // MARK: - UITextViewDelegate
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textViewDirtyCount += 1
        perform(#selector(TableViewTextViewCell.queuedTextVewDidChange),
                with: nil,
                afterDelay: 0.3) // Wait until typing stopped
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textViewDirtyCount = 0 // initialize queuedTextVewDidChange
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textViewDirtyCount = -1 // prevent any further queuedTextVewDidChange
    }

    func queuedTextVewDidChange() {
        if textViewDirtyCount > 0 {
            textViewDirtyCount -= 1
            if 0 == textViewDirtyCount, let refreshCell = refreshCell {
                refreshCell()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Dequeue & update closure:**

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewTextViewCell

    cell.refreshCell = {
        () -> Void in
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    return cell
}
```

---

Notice the 0.3 seconds delay *after* the last character has been entered ; if less than 0.3 seconds has elapsed since the last change, no update takes place. This significantly reduces flickering.

[image: Frame Delay]

[↻ replay animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00uDU.gif)

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-35259289) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-35259289).

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but this still isn't an appropriate solution when the primary focus of the interface involves editing text. Every new line is obscured until the user stops typing, which can become even more glaring if text attachments are involved. Hopefully others will find this answer useful, though.

Comment: I experience the obscured line until the 2nd word. No worries on the effort, it is in a shipped product. Clearly, I am very interested in a robust, universal solution.

Answer (score 3):

The beginUpdates method works if you disable UIView animations before calling it.

```
//inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath
cell.performCellUpdates = { [unowned self] in
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)   //the secret sauce, prevents the jitter
    self.tv.beginUpdates()
    self.tv.endUpdates()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)    //don't forget to turn animations back on
}
   
...

//inside of cell subclass
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.sizeToFit()
    performCellUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried this early on… Unfortunately, this approach prevents the table view from scrolling at all while the user edits the text (even when the text view's cursor winds up outside the visible content area), so it wasn't usable in my case. This method doesn't cause "jittering" though, so it could be sufficient for others.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the height of an existing `UITableViewCell`. You want to tell the `UITableView` that cell is invalid, and reload it.

At the time the cell is reloaded (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`) you can then pass the new, updated cell. And you trigger a single cell refresh with `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)`

`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is not as drastic are `reloadData()`. It is a punctual index refresh, does not need to be surrounded by `tableView.beginUpdates` and `tableView.endUpdates`, and you get to supply an animation method of your choice, such as `.Fade`.

See `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_:withRowAnimation:)` in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:).

---

Also visit [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34997679/218152) which describes changing a cell height in details.

[image: Animated demo]

Comment: Well, indeed you don't have to reload the cell…the documentation for `beginUpdates` states, "You can also use this method followed by the `endUpdates` method to animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell." However, a _layout_ pass is nevertheless performed for the entire table view, which scrolls it to the top, disrupting text input.

Comment: I have clarified my answer: invoking `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)` is all you need to trigger the refresh of a single cell and it's height.

Comment: The approach I described above already updates the layout without reloading any cells. Since the text view in my cell updates as the user edits text, reloading the cell doesn't appear to be an option (at least not that I've figured out).

My question is whether there's a way to specify that only the specific cell with updated content needs to be laid out. Going by the start of your post, I guess there isn't.

Comment: There is this conundrum described on http://stackoverflow.com/a/26599389/218152: **(1)** If you use `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` with `scrollEnabled=false`, you end up jittering uncontrollably when text gets large, since the table is redrawn from top-down, then scrolls back to insertion point. **(2)** If you use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, you loose the editing. An approach consists in tie `scrollEnabled` for the `UITextView` to `becomeFirstResponder/resignFirstResponder`. Visual effect: the cell only resizes when editing is complete.